# In Rails, how do I use the same form for both creating and updating my object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  So as not to duplicate too much code, I'd like to use the same form for both creating and updating my object.  I would like the form to submit to my controller's create method for creating ...

```
  def create
    @user_notification = UserNotification.new(user_notification_params)
    ...
  end
```

and its update method for updating ...

```
  def update
    ...
  end
```

I have this form, which works fine for creating ...

```
<%= form_for @user_notification, :url => user_notifications_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
    ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price, 'Price' %> <span class="required">*</span> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :price, :size => 30 %>
  </div>
    ...
```

but when it comes to updating, I get this error upon submitting my update request ...

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/user_notifications"
```

I have defined this in my config/routes.rb file

```
  resources 'user_notifications'
```

But I sense the problem is deeper than a routes issue.  How do I adjust my form definition.  Is there any way to use the same partial for both creating and updating, and if so, what adjustments do I need to make to the above?

Comment: The easiest way to figure this out is to generate a scaffold. A scaffold will give you default views, including a partial form to use in both your create and edit actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem you may be having is that you are explicitly setting the URL in your form:

```
form_for @user_notification, :url => user_notifications_path
```

the `user_notifications_path` will match to two routes depending on the request method. using `user_notifications_path` with a GET will match to the index action, and with a POST will match to the create action.

For your case you require `user_notification_path`, notice it is singular. this helper will match to the show action on a GET request, update action on a PUT/PATCH request, and destroy action on a DELETE request.

When using form_for, you should be able to get the desired effect without explicitly setting the URL:

```
form_for @user_notification
```

Rails will automatically set the correct URL and request method based on whether the model in `@user_notification` is a new record or not, and automatically attempt to find the correct routes for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use render to help [rails render guilde](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)
here is sample code

first rename your form to _user_notification.html.erb (note: please make sure you added _ in front of file name

and in you new.html.erb and edit.html.erb, use render to call it

```
<%= render 'user_notification' %>
```